# В чем смысл использования библиотеки jcstress если я не пишу concurrent библиотеку для многопоточнсти

Tags: java, многопоточность

Мне дали ученическое задание по теме многопоточности, звучит оно так: "Продемонстрировать проблемы при использовании библиотеки `jcstress`.

Я начал гуглить, и понял так, что это библиотека для тестирования `concurrent` алгоритмов, которые которые решают проблему потерь при обработке разделяемых ресурсов в многопоточности. А решают ее тем, что для каждого потока, создают временную копию разделяемого объекта, и потом сливают результат в оригинал. И если это все так, то получается, что эта библиотека никому кроме создателей `concurrent collections` и не нужна?

Или у нее есть и другие области применения, просто я не понял?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру, вы пишете код, который параллельно обрабатывает каким-либо образом картинку (к примеру, переводит в серый). Этот код может работать всегда верно, но в один день случится такое чередование, что вы дважды перепишете один и тот же пиксель и в итоге он превратится в красный. Можно избежать этой ошибки, если много раз запускать стресс тест, который скорее всего выявит ошибку.